# 都内 is reserved for the capital Tokyo, what term is used to mean a foreign capital city?

Tags: word-choice, words

I have seen the term used in reference to Tokyo. What would the term be for a foreign capital？

Comment: try an internet search. I found some sites that would help you answer or at the very least reshape your question.

Comment: Seems exclusive to Japan and China.

Comment: the kanji might have a meaning in Chinese, but if you look at only Japanese sites, to see how they use the phrase, the pattern quickly becomes clear. Also check KotoBank.

Comment: Only in Japan, a special district.

Comment: My question is requesting the term for foreign capital districts.

Comment: In what context do you want to use the term? Would something like パリ市内, ロンドン市内, 北京市内 etc. not work? 東京は「都」だけど、ロンドン、パリ、北京とかって「市」ですよね？いや、「区」の場合もあるのかな？

Comment: the capital cities

Comment: If you are looking for the Japanese equivalent to the word "Capital city", then it's 首都

Comment: ^ じゃあ、「[首都内]{しゅとない}」になるのかも・・？

Comment: Seems like a matter of opinion, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What people usually imagine as the capital city is only eastern 23 wards of 東京都, while 都内 means the whole area of 東京都, including some remote mountainous regions (also see [my previous post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/50204/7810)).

This term **都【と】** is not used because of the fact that an area is the capital of a state (strictly speaking, [Tokyo is not the *de jure* capital of Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_of_Japan)), but because it is a first-level administrative division that is distinguished from other provinces by a special classification of "Capital" or "Metropolis".

As far as I know, Bangkok, Thailand, is the only region Japanese Ministry of Foreign Affairs officially translates as バンコク都 ([example](https://www.anzen.mofa.go.jp/info/pchazardspecificinfo_2015T075.html)). Besides, Phnom Penh, Cambodia ([example](http://open_jicareport.jica.go.jp/618/618/618_109_12270278.html)) and Vientiane, Laos ([example](http://open_jicareport.jica.go.jp/618/618/618_109_12270278.html)) are often referred to as 都. In these cases, the extent of region can be formally called 都内 and the residents 都民, except that not many people practically use 都 for any foreign region in ordinary speech.

Most of special capital areas in other countries call themselves "City", thus translated 市. Washington DC is 特別区, Jakarta is 特別州, and so on.